# How do I disable: [js] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

The following is what I want to disable:

[image: [js] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.]

I can't find it in settings.
Help appreciated as this is really annoying.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is a new feature added in Visual Studio Code called "Suggestion Code Actions". "Suggestion Code Actions" are enabled by default in JavaScript and TypeScript.

You can disable them by setting: `"typescript.suggestionActions.enabled": false` or `"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false` in your user/workspace settings. The documentation can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

[image]
<sub>(Image provided by [Yusuf Yaşar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11059630/yusuf-ya%C5%9Far).)</sub>

Comment: Is there any way to turn off only this warning and not all suggestions?

Comment: Yep, that works, thank you, although it would be nice to only turn off that warning.

Comment: Thread linked above ends up with "*I don't understand why this is closed. The problem exists*" and "*I've locked this issue because +1 comments are causing people to miss that there is already is a solution to disable these hints.*". I don't know what's wrong with Microsoft, or why they purposefully ignore to acknowledge that there's a problem.

Comment: in that thread nobody asked how to turn off suggestions only that turn off es6 import suggestions for nodejs files, eslint you define what module you want yet it can't read eslint config?

Comment: Still an issue in August 2019, there's no way to disable just this action that I've been able to find.

Comment: @NatoBoram Thank goddess TypeScript is open source, so I found a way to turn off this warning via mangling with TypeScript's source code. Check my answer if you are still bothered by this problem.

Comment: Sadly this still seems to be an issue moving towards the end of 2020

Comment: I get this warning when declare a variable like this `var logger = require('./logger');` in VS Code. As it is my first day to use JavaScript, I'd like to keep it for now to see what is the consequence after.

Comment: @apena It seems only disable the 80001 issue, because the 6133 issue is stills prompted when I edit the js file.

Comment: Any updates in 2020? How can I disable only warning 80001?

Answer (score 49):

For anyone using Vim with [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim), you can make the same change by adding the same in the `:CocConfig` object:

```
"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false
```

If you haven't added any settings to `:CocConfig` before, then you need to make sure the above setting is wrapped in a JSON object:

```
{
    "javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this stop all suggestions related to JS ?

Comment: @ParsaNoori yes it does, there isn't a more precise way of doing it unfortunately - see the [comments in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582984/how-do-i-disable-js-file-is-a-commonjs-module-it-may-be-converted-to-an-es6/63522707?noredirect=1#comment86402584_49693760)

Answer (score 31):

For anyone using Neovim with Native LSP and [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) for setting up your language servers, you can disable suggestions by adding this somewhere in your tsserver setup:

```
require('lspconfig').tsserver.setup({
    init_options = {
        preferences = {
            disableSuggestions = true,
        },
    },
})
```

You can also use the [nvim-lsp-ts-utils](https://github.com/jose-elias-alvarez/nvim-lsp-ts-utils) plugin to filter out this specific diagnostic message while keeping suggestions enabled by adding this somewhere in your tsserver setup:

```
require('lspconfig').tsserver.setup({
    on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
        require('nvim-lsp-ts-utils').setup({
            filter_out_diagnostics_by_code = { 80001 },
        })
        require('nvim-lsp-ts-utils').setup_client(client)
    end,
})
```

Comment: I followed this but it's not working for me :/ I've contrasted this info with the official Lsp documentation and typescript-language-server docs and it seems to be right. However the message keeps appearing, don't know why.

Comment: Make sure you're not calling setup on tsserver more than once. You need to add the init_options block inside your existing setup call.

Comment: Thanks I double checked and the issue was that I was overwriting the on_attach property in the second call. Removed that and the message disappeared.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also was getting an issue with this not working. Turns out calling jose-elias-alvarez/typescript.nvim's automatically calls the LSP setup a second time, which overwrites the former call.

Comment: Relevant link for preferences.disableSuggestions: https://github.com/typescript-language-server/typescript-language-server/blob/master/docs/configuration.md/#preferences-options

Answer (score 18):

*Alert! This approach might be too much for VSCode users who love the intelligent coding assistance. Use it as a simple & quick help, together with other linting & testing utilities.*

---

The control of the presence of the said message is located in `Settings => Extensions => TypeScript`.  ***(TypeScript !!! :P)***

As shown in screenshot, I searched in Settings with keyword "validate", then click TypeScript. It's the first item.

[image]

Comment: This is disabling *all validation* for javascript.  Kind of a "throwing the baby out with the bathwater" situation.

Comment: yes, it was too much for me ))

Answer (score 10):

Actually this annoying suggestion comes from TypeScript.

Thus, to turn off this suggestion, you can modify the source code of TypeScript, compile it, then tell vscode to use your fork of TypeScript.

As a quick and dirty hack, just remove the logic related to `ts.Diagnostics.File_is_a_CommonJS_module_it_may_be_converted_to_an_ES6_module`, then compile the project following the instructions on TypeScript's README.

The compilation will fail because removing the related logic causes some functions become unused, then you just remove those unused function definitions and recompile the project (`gulp clean && gulp local`).

After you successfully compile your fork of TypeScript, then change your user settings.json to point to your vscode fork:

```
"typescript.tsdk": "/path/to/your/fork/of/TypeScript/built/local",
```

Done.

Restart your vscode, and the annoying suggestion has gone.

You can check [this commit](https://github.com/weakish/TypeScript/commit/5d5aab4fb1f14cac00c68116681da1e0b1b20107) to see which source files of TypeScript need to be modify.

Warn: the modification is quick and dirty, use them at your own risk. If you find anything wrong, you can just remove the tsdk configuration, to switch back to vscode's built-in TypeScript.

Comment: It is so tedious and how can I upgrade?

Comment: @Run To upgrade, just pull the typescript repository and repeat the process again. But this is an outdated answer. Recent versions of TypeScript still have not fixed this issue?

Answer (score 10):

If your project is `"type": "module"` and you need to have a CommonJS file in it, e.g. to configure ESLint (which doesn't support ESM as of writing this), then just rename it from `*.js` to `*.cjs` (or from `*.ts` to `*.cts`, if appropriate), and the suggestion will go away. [The fix for this has shipped with TypeScript 4.5.1 about a year ago](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46240).

Comment: Great answer, renaming `.eslint.js` to `.cjs` makes much more sense than turning suggestions in the editor!

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error in Next js, try the code below.

1. Next.js includes the "next/babel" preset to your app, which includes everything needed to compile React applications and server-side code.
2. Open your .eslintrc.json

   ```
   { "extends" : "next/babel" }
   ```
3. But if you want to extend the default Babel configs, it's also possible.
   https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config

Answer (score 1):

For those using Neovim, you can ignore specifically just this diagnostic by overriding the LSP handler for `publishDiagnostics`.

I'm using Neovim v0.9.2 and lspconfig. If you're not using lspconfig, I think you can still override the LSP handler using [`vim.lsp.with()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html#lsp-handler-configuration).

```lua
require('lspconfig').typescript.setup {
    handlers = {
        ["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = function(_, result, ctx, config)
            if result.diagnostics ~= nil then
                local idx = 1
                while idx <= #result.diagnostics do
                    if result.diagnostics[idx].code == 80001 then
                        table.remove(result.diagnostics, idx)
                    else
                        idx = idx + 1
                    end
                end
            end
            vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics(_, result, ctx, config)
        end,
    }
}
```

I found this out from [How to ignore tsserver error: "File is a commonjs module..."](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/nv3qh8/comment/h1tx1rh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on r/neovim, but then adapted the code to work for my version of Neovim.

Answer (score 0):

#### For Neovim Users

Much credit goes to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294761/8604951) but it won't work if you're using the [pmizio/typescript-tools.nvim](https://github.com/pmizio/typescript-tools.nvim) plugin for the LSP support (and much more!). And if you're using the same plugin like me, you'll need the following slightly updated configurations:

```lua
require('typescript-tools).setup({
  settings = {
    tsserver_file_preferences = {
      disableSuggestions = true,
    },
  },
})
```

For more advanced configuration of your TypeScript development I strongly recommend checking out the repository which contains additional information.

Answer (score -10):

Maybe you don't have `function(request, response)`,
try it. It works for me

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.