# Error "File is a commonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module. ts(80001)"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, commonjs

Developing javascript in vscode, I see this error on line `const Koa = require("Koa");`:

> File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module. ts(80001)

and after I search found only 1 solution to disable all suggestionActions.

how I disable only "require" error without disabling all suggestionActions?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47299

Comment: The Github link in Dilshan's comment is not an answer, OP says WITHOUT disabling the setting that that Github link says to disable.

Comment: Why does Microsoft ignore this issue all the time instead of correcting it? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47299

Comment: Effectively the answer to this question is that there is no granular option it's all or nothing. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/49582984/327074

Answer (score 7):

Use the `.cjs` file extension instead of `.js` to note that the file will remain a CommonJS module instead of an ES6 module (`.mjs`).  You will still get other code suggestionActions this way.

Comment: More information: https://codingforseo.com/blog/mjs-vs-cjs-files/

Answer (score -1):

It's hinting to convert the code to support ES module standards. ES module is a standard module format that both browsers and the backend node environment support.