# Visual Studio Code failed to import node module package

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, node-modules

I am new to Node.js and I am trying to import module exports `module.exports`. But it does not give me any auto suggestions and displays a quick fix (an error) of that line.

**logger.js**

```
var url = 'https://www.google.com';

function log(message){
    //send http request
    console.log(message);

}
 module.exports.log = log;
```

**error.**

```
var module: {
    "d:/NotitiaZone/Node/logger": typeof import("d:/NotitiaZone/Node/logger");
}
File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.ts(80001)
```

> my **node version** -v10.16.3 
>  my **npm versoin** - 6.9.0

I have already installed below extensions.

[image: d]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable: \[js\] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582984/how-do-i-disable-js-file-is-a-commonjs-module-it-may-be-converted-to-an-es6)