# List of VSCode javascript/typescript suggestionActions

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, autosuggest, coc.nvim

VSCode/coc-tsserver suggest code actions. According to answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582984/how-do-i-disable-js-file-is-a-commonjs-module-it-may-be-converted-to-an-es6), you can disable these. There are a few I find annoying, so I wanted to disable them, but I don't want to inadvertently disable useful features. Is there a list of all possible code suggestions that will be made? [This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_code-suggestions) only talks about 1 (converting `.then`s to `async/await`s), and [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings) (ctrl-f for "suggestionActions") only says "Enable/disable suggestion diagnostics" with no information about *what* the suggestions are.