# Cannot Get VSCode to Work With Firebase Functions in TypeScript, Compilation and AutoComplete

Tags: typescript, firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions, vscode-extensions

This seems like a very obvious problem, but there is no online guide that solves this for me, and as such I think a clear solution to this would be super beneficial to the internet! Hence I am offering all the incentive I can.

There's multiple problems, wrapped into one and I am looking for a solution that works with correct code formatting onsave, and fixes the VSCode compilation warnings.

I create a firebase functions project, and set eslint to true, and also set typescript.
With my current VSCode settings, I immediately get 2 compilation errors:

in my index.ts file there is a red squiggly below import (however VSCode does not let me see what the error is)

[image]

And then, as you can see here, in the .eslintrc.js file there is an error complaining that the file is a CommonJS module:

[image]

If I ignore these errors (or try and refactor the latter) I still cannot deploy the firebase functions, because it complains that there are linter problems.

**However, I am trying to use a code formatter on save that applies the same linting rules. I cannot determine how to do this!** I have tried ESLint VSCode extension, I have tried Prettier VSCode extension, but I'm unclear how to apply the same rules.

Advice on how to format the appropriate rules on save, as well as remove the compilation issues in VSCode would be super appreciated!

Comment: I have the same exact problem, I wish someone could actually give a clear answer to this, I'm stuck and I literally can't write functions.

Comment: remove the firebase linter for now but ya long term cant find a working guide

Comment: Can you follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693760), where it is mentioned how to disable the warning message?