# Stuck on Command/Event Handlers in discord.js guide using ESM

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been working through creating this bot using discord.js and I just can't for the life of me figure out how to use the command and event handler with ESM.

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#reading-command-files

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#individual-event-files

**EDIT:**

So I made a few changes to my code.

This is the code in my index.js

```
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Collection } from 'discord.js';
import 'dotenv/config';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import url from 'url';

const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds],
});

client.commands = new Collection();
const __dirname = url.fileURLToPath(new URL('.', import.meta.url));

const commandsPath = path.dirname(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync(commandsPath)
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const filePath = path.dirname(commandsPath, file);
  const { default: command } = await import(filePath);
  client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in!`);
});
```

This is the code in my deployCommand.js file

```
import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest';
import { Routes } from 'discord.js';
import 'dotenv/config';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import url from 'url';

const __dirname = url.fileURLToPath(new URL('.', import.meta.url));
const commands = [];
const commandsPath = path.dirname(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync(commandsPath)
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const filePath = path.dirname(commandsPath, file);
  const { default: command } = await import(filePath);
  commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

rest
  .put(
    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(
      process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      process.env.GUILD_ID
    ),
    { body: commands }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
  .catch(console.error);
```

I am no longer receiving any errors. However, the problem I am running into is - I don't believe my deployCommand.js code is running at all.

```
console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
```

This part of the code is not showing up. I only get notified that the bot was logged in.

**EDIT 2**

I definitely narrowed it down to my use of `path.dirname`

If I `console.log(__dirname);` I get the correct path, but whenever I try to search for the commands folder I receive an error.

> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in:
> file, data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows,
> absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'

I've tried `path.join` `join` by itself `path.normalize` and `__dirname + 'commands'`

Comment: I think it has something to do with `path.dirname` but if I use `join`  I get "Received protocol 'c:'"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix using `require()` and `import`.

If you are wanting to use `import` you will need to edit your code to remove all instances of require and replace it with import statements and edit your `package.json` to include

```json
{
    "type": "module
}
```

If you're only changing it because VSC is showing this notice - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582984/how-do-i-disable-js-file-is-a-commonjs-module-it-may-be-converted-to-an-es6) to disable it.
[image: File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module.ts(80001)]

Comment: I should have been clearer. I replace require with import, but I can't seem to get any of the rest of the code working with modules. I'm not sure what the correct replacements are for parts like `path.join` `__dirname`

Comment: import { join } from 'path';

Comment: "'join' is declared but its value is never read."

Comment: actually use it then lol, you need to use the join function... just do join(__dirname + 'whatever')

Comment: I went back and used it but it didn't seem to make a difference, still got the same error. I seemed to fix it in my second edit but I'm still running into the type error for .toJSON

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `import` in node,you must change the value of the `type`option in `package.json` to `module`

Comment: Sorry, please see my edits. I should have been clearer.

Comment: I took a closer look at your code and found that you used `import` to reference a file, when you use `import()` to reference a file the result he returns is a `Promise`.

details : https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import

Comment: Thanks for this, I updated and put all the code I have if you wouldn't mind taking a look at the edits.